# Cloudflare Filters / Firewall API - My script stopped working after two IP addresses

Tags: bash, api, curl, firewall, cloudflare

I'm trying to use the Cloudflare API to dynamically update a single specific firewall rule.
I'm using a bash script to:

- Grab the latest IP addresses within my Cloudflare firewall rule.
- Pass in a new IP address to be added to the firewall using the `$1` variable.
- Use the Filters API to update the firewall rule with the new IP address.

Here's the full bash script I'm using to try and achieve this. (I might not be doing things in the most efficient way, but I'm new to bash overall)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Cloudflare Email
EMAIL='someone@example.com'
# API Key
TOKEN='Token'
# Zone ID
ZONE='Zone'
# Firewall ID
ID='ID'
# Rule Filter
FILTER='Filter'

# Grab Cloudflare firewall rule we want to update:
RULE=$(
    curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$ZONE/firewall/rules/$ID?id=$ID" \
    -H "X-Auth-Email: $EMAIL" \
    -H "X-Auth-Key: $TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"
)

# Filter the response to just show IPv4 and IPv6 addresses:
OLD=$(
    jq -r '.result.filter.expression | capture(".*{(?<ips>[^}]*)}").ips' <<<"$RULE"
)

# Debug
echo $OLD

# Use the filters API to update the expression
curl -X PUT \
    -H "X-Auth-Email: $EMAIL" \
    -H "X-Auth-Key: $TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
    "id": "ID",
    "paused": false,
    "expression": "(ip.src in {'$OLD' '$1'})"
}' "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$ZONE/filters/$FILTER"
```

Running this script when there are *two* IP address in the firewall rule [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRtXX.png) works perfectly.

The response is also all good:

```json
{
  "result": {
    "id": "ID",
    "paused": false,
    "expression": "(ip.src in {192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2})"
  },
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": []
}
```

But, when I run the script a third time, with a different IP address I get this `curl` error.

```sh
$ bash test.sh 192.168.1.3
192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2    <--- Just Debug
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 24:
192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3})"
}
                       ^
```

I don't understand why it works for two IP's but three it doesn't. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thank you so much, let me know if anyone needs additional information!

Comment: Try `set -x` to see the exact command that is being run.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Does this provide some insights?

```bash
curl -X PUT -H 'X-Auth-Email: someone@example.com' -H 'X-Auth-Key: API' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "id": "FILTER",
    "expression": "(ip.src in {192.168.1.1' '192.168.1.2 162.168.1.3})"
}' https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/ZONE/filters/FILTER
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 24:
192.168.1.2 162.168.1.3})"
}
```

Comment: `$OLD` and `$1` are interpolated in the middle of a single-quoted string (the `-d` option to `curl`), but aren't themselves protected by any quotes at the shell level. You should double-quote them both, i.e. `ip.src in {'"$OLD"' '"$1"'})`. Yes, the quoting is confusing, because there are both shell quotes (double- and single-) and quotes that're part of the expression, all mixed together. Sorry. BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) spots this problem and suggests a correct fix.

Comment: There are some alternate solutions to a similar problem here: ["How to execute a command that has many nested single and double quotes with a quoted variable in bash"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527896/how-to-execute-a-command-that-has-many-nested-single-and-double-quotes-with-a-qu)

Comment: I see some stray literal single quotes in `"(ip.src in {192.168.1.1' '192.168.1.2 162.168.1.3})"`.